# OpenLDAP - How to identify Zimbra's internal LDAP authentication credentials

Tags: authentication, openldap, zimbra

I need to identify Zimbra's internal LDAP's (based on OpenLDAP) authentication credentials in order to manage authentications using Spring LDAP template. So I need `base` and `userDn` information. How can I get this information from Zimbra?

Answer (score -1):

It would be:
Base DN = ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com
User DN = uid=zimbra

Comment: Only if you assume that every LDAP DIT in the world is based at dc=my domain,dc=com and that the next level is ou=people and that the Zimbra userid is under it. It isn't so.

Comment: Exactly my point. It works on one installation. It would work on many. It doesn't work on all, for the reasons I gave.